# 'str' object is not callable in caesar encryptor

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, encryption, caesar-cipher

```
def encrypt_caesar(plaintext):
    s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    d = dict(map(s,s[3:]+ s[:3]))
    return ''.join(map(lambda l: d.get(l,l), plaintext.lower()))
```

Tried to copy this code from Stanford lecture slide and run it but it gives `'str' object is not callable` error, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you expect the `map()` to produce? You are trying to use `s` as a *function* there.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the author of the slide didn't actually *test* the code.

The code you produced is trying to use `map()` to call `s` as a function:

```
map(s,s[3:]+ s[:3])
#   ^ This must be a *callable object*, like a function
```

If you wanted to create a dictionary mapping ASCII letters to a letter 3 spots along in the alphabet, use the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) instead:

```
d = dict(zip(s, s[3:] + s[:3]))
```

`zip()` then pairs up each element in `s` with each element in `s[3:] + s[:3]`, and those `(letter, letter + 3)` pairs are then passed to `dict()` to form key-value pairs:

```
>>> s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
>>> dict(zip(s, s[3:] + s[:3]))
{'A': 'D', 'I': 'L', 'L': 'O', 'X': 'A', 'N': 'Q', 'D': 'G', 'S': 'V', 'B': 'E', 'V': 'Y', 'C': 'F', 'K': 'N', 'W': 'Z', 'R': 'U', 'O': 'R', 'T': 'W', 'P': 'S', 'F': 'I', 'J': 'M', 'M': 'P', 'E': 'H', 'Q': 'T', 'H': 'K', 'G': 'J', 'Z': 'C', 'U': 'X', 'Y': 'B'}
```

Next, your last line will completely *fail* to do any encryption, because your map only handles **uppercase letters**, but you **lowercased** your input. Either produce a lowercase map, or lowercase your input.

Lowercasing the map could look like this:

```
def encrypt_caesar(plaintext):
    s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    d = dict(zip(s, s[3:] + s[:3]))
    return ''.join(map(lambda l: d.get(l, l), plaintext.lower()))
```

or you could just use the [`string.ascii_lowercase` constant](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

def encrypt_caesar(plaintext):
    d = dict(zip(ascii_lowercase, ascii_lowercase[3:] + ascii_lowercase[:3]))
    return ''.join(map(lambda l: d.get(l,l), plaintext.lower()))
```

Using this method is *rather slow*, however. For blazingly-fast 'encryption', use the [`str.translate()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate); the input map for that is best produced with [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as alc

def encrypt_caesar(plaintext, shift=3):
    map = str.maketrans(alc, alc[shift:] + alc[:shift])
    return plaintext.lower().translate(map)
```

I added a `shift` parameter to define how much of an alphabet shift should be applied.

I'll leave handling both lowercase and uppercase letters as an exercise to the reader!

Comment: You are very correct sir, it appears I can't even copy a code correctly :(